# Looking for some advice with python code for employee table question

Tags: python

I have to code this in python:

Suppose the weekly hours for all employees are stored in a table. Each row records an employee’s seven-day work hours with seven columns. For example, the following table stores the work hours for eight employees. Write a program that inputs the hours of all employees and displays employees and their total hours in decreasing order of the total hours.

I have difficulties understanding how to input the parameters (hours per employee) and store for each one while sum it for each.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: make emp table with day table relation and map time details there

Answer (score 0):

The program has to be broken down into the following

1. A database with at least two tables
2. An application/code layer to connect to the database for storing and retrieving values

For Task 1, do the following
Create two tables
Table one is for employee, it will have columns employeeid(auto number,pkey), fullname(text field)

Table two is for hours, it will have ten columns, id(autonumber,pkey),employeeid(foreignkey with employee table),day1_hour(number  field),day2_hour(number  field),day3_hour(number  field),day4_hour(number  field),day5_hour(number  field),day6_hour(number  field),day7_hour(number  field),total_hour(number  field)

Then you need a python application written to insert records, this can be done in django, flask or any of your preferred choice.

Finally a select query(SQL) will be written to retrieve the records, the syntax of the Select statement will be determined by the database system you are using, e.g sql lite, mysql,ms sql.

Answer (score 0):

[Data Sample Here: Employee vs Worked Hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGMXt.png)

```
import csv

employeeDictionary = {}
currentEmployee = ''
theCSV = csv.DictReader(open('filePATH.csv'), delimiter=',')  # read csv file
for theRow in theCSV:
    for key, val in theRow.items():  # theRow is a dictionary
        if key == 'Employee':
            currentEmployee = val
            employeeDictionary[currentEmployee] = []  # create dictionary entry with employeeName as key, value is a list
        else:
            employeeDictionary[currentEmployee].append(int(val))
    employeeDictionary[currentEmployee] = sum(employeeDictionary[currentEmployee])  # once done with the row, add all hours for currentEmployee

employeeTotalHoursWorked = dict(sorted(employeeDictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))  # sorts dictionary decreasing

print(employeeTotalHoursWorked)
```

Comment: Result is a dictionary that has total hours worked for each employee.